# Can I draw an image on canvas and then change its coordinates

Tags: android, image, canvas, coordinates

When user clicked on the screen, I can draw image using Canvas.drawBitmap(). Then I wanna change its coordinates. But I can't. I tried a lot of methods. Some tutorials on the internet gives drag and drop examples. But it wants the user to press longer time. I must be able to change its coordinates instantenously. How can I do that?

Comment: you want to draw it at a position then  redraw it in another one ??

Comment: No, not another one. I wanna use the drawn bitmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to draw the `Bitmap` again in those coordinates. Before you do so, use `Canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)` to clear the screen.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible as you've described, however there are two possibilities to achieve your goal. First use [Canvas.drawBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) there are a series of methods to make transformation of the image easy. Second use Canvas set transformation you can think of this as "moving/scrolling/scaling" (more exactly transforming) the viewable area of the Canvas. To move the image around hook into SurfaceView's onTouch handler.

Comment: Sorry, It is not drawImage. I used drawBitmap() as you said. But written wrong above. Actually, I don't understand how I can use the bitmap that was created before. Draw but how to use it as an object?
Bitmap _scratch = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);  
canvas.drawBitmap(_scratch, touched_x, touched_y, null);

Comment: So why not drawBitmap in a different location using a different x and y?

Comment: I don't want the old one and Che's answer worked for me. Thanks for your time :)